# How to show a detailsview in jquery dialog after selecting record in gridview (all in the same page)

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui-dialog, webforms

I have web forms page that has 2 controls. A gridview and an associated listview.

When i select the record in gridview the page posts back and i see the details of the gridline in listview which is located below the grid.

Now i want to transfer the listview to a jquery dialog control.

I have tried to find a solid way to do it but i am confused. the moment the dialog appears its closed , apparently because the postbaxk occurs in order for the detailsview to load..

Any suggestions?

Should i have to drop listview in a separate page and then call the page from the grid inside a jquery dialog? (how?)

Is there a way to call the listview and show it in a dialog box instead of showing it below the gris?

Thanks

Update1: Tried some things. Created a hidden field which i update based on the clicks from the controls. If the value of the field falls in a value that i define then i load the dialog on page_load , if not then it doesnt show. this works , but i am having problem with the edit/insert in the listview in the dialog...seems that it doesnt work...

Comment: Are you showing single record in your Listview for GridView row details ?

Comment: Yes. I care to show one record in the listview depending on the grid view that the user clicked. I got an answer from asp.net forums which seems logical. To load the dialog in every page load from jquery. then to determine which control caused the postback in order not to show the dialog every time. Up to here is ok, but i have a problem in the edit/insert operation in the listview. It doesnt work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a postback is required after you load the details in the listview, you need to spit out javascript code during the postback that will put the listview into a jquery dialog.

One way is this:

```
<div id="dialogHolder"><!-- this is just a div enclosing the listview -->
    <asp:listview runat="server"...
</div>
```

Now, when you do the postback to populate the listview with the details, do this:

```
private void populateListView()//
{
     //code to populate listview above
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"dialogscript","$('#dialogHolder').dialog('open');",true);       
}
```

Comment: Isn't it the same as to show the dialog in the page load event of jquery?

Comment: Yes, it's the same... you are basically executing a `$(document).ready(function(){});...` the difference is that you only trigger it when the listview has been populated and from the server-side.

Comment: Why do you want to keep listview in the div? Why not the Table and TR/TD ? It's a matter of just one record. Right?

Answer (score 0):

What i have found to work up to know is this:

```
if ($("#cphMain_HiddenField1").val() == "dlg") {
    $("#divTodo_Details").dialog({ show: 'fade', hide: 'fade', autoOpen: true, modal: true, title: "Details", width: 1024 });
}
//
$(".showdetails").click(function () {
    $("#cphMain_HiddenField1").val("dlg");
});
//
$(".NOshowdetails").click(function () {
    $("#cphMain_HiddenField1").val("");
});
```

In my aspx markup i give the class showdetails and NOshowdetails to whatever controls i want so during the postback the dialog appears only on the controls i want.

p.s. i also have a hiddenfield to hold the value which i am checking on page_load.